# Dataloader API limits exceeded

Tags: api, data-loader

We were loading lots of data in org and suddenly errors like *Cannot obtain exclusive rights on records* and then *API limits exceeded.*
I did some research and founded salesforce reset its limits every 24 hours.
so how can i know when limit will be resetted by sales force.

How can i calculate when 24 hours will be over.Is this i can look at company information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have expired API limits you can look in company Information

[image]

If you have expired Bulk API Limits ,You can monitor via Bulk Data load jobs

[image]

Comment: If this helped ,please mark as answered to help community

Comment: Please guide me on more thing,what can we do avoid hitting this limit.Can we ask sales force to increase limits, Also then how much sales force can increase,

Comment: This needs to be a separate question .Community can help you with answer. In short yes you can purchase more API but not more bulk API.Your no of API depends on no of license

Comment: Wonderful, you are awesome. I will write another question for that..Thanks

Comment: Also, the limit is a rolling 24 hour window, updated hourly. So if you use your limit in one hour, you have to wait for 24 hours later.

Comment: Is there any way I can check whether limit quota exceeded before firing a call?